# Including Large Static HTML File with Image in MVC View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm converting a desktop application that hosts HTML content into an online application. I have various large pieces of prebuilt static html that need to be included in an MVC page depending on user actions. Each of the static html pages includes at least one `img` tag that references a file that, in a Web Forms page would be located in the same directory. Here's a very simplified example:

Static html:

```
<html>
<!-- Large chunk of html -->
<img src="logo.gif" >
<!-- More html -->
</html>
```

SampleController:

```
Dim html as String = GetFileContentAsString("~/Content/Sample/Static.html")
ViewBag.StaticHTML = PrepareHTMLContent(html)
```

View:

```
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.StaticHTML)
```

The result of the above is a page (e.g. `http://localhost:12345/Sample`) with a broken image link in the middle of the HTML. I'm already preprocessing the html where possible to strip out useless tags and insert Javascript and CSS links but preprocessing the image paths is unreliable because they could be anywhere in the static html and are quite likely to be inconsistent or otherwise quirky.

So how can I place (or create) the image file in the right location for the static html to pick it up? Is there any other option (bearing in mind that I also need to link CSS and JavaScript files and that the static html has a bunch of other files associated with it that need to be kept in a single location)?

Or is there a way to define or override the location the dynamic MVC page is built?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing would be to have /Sample return an HTML page that simply loads /~Content/Sample/Static.html into an iframe so that the browser will resolve relative paths in static.html to be within /~Content/Sample/